# Laravel seeder doesn't seed password

Tags: php, database, laravel, seeding

I want to seed users to database but seeder doesn't create password.

**I have This migration File**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

}

**and this Seeder file**

```
// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        DB::table('users')->truncate();

        foreach(range(1, 3) as $index)
        {
            $user = User::create(array(
                'password' => $faker->word,
                'username' => $faker->userName,
                'email' => $faker->email
            ));
        }


    }

}
```

I did `php artisan migrate` and it said **"nothing to migrate"**

so now when I do **php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder** it throws no error.

Any idea why seeder does not create username? I have just empty column in my database...

thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Tried adding `Eloquent::unguard();` before the start of the foreach loop?

Also, migration (`php artisan migrate` command) is only concerned with running the migrations (creating the database not populating). Alternately you can include on your DatabaseSeeder `$this->call('UsersTableSeeder');` then you can run `php artisan migrate --seed`

Comment: That helped :) post it like a answe so i can rate it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `Eloquent::unguard();` before the start of the `foreach()` loop.

---

Also, migration (`php artisan migrate` command) is only concerned with running the migrations (creating the database not populating).

Alternately you can include on your DatabaseSeeder `$this->call('UsersTableSeeder');` then you can run `php artisan migrate --seed`